# Selling Story Maps via ArcGIS Marketplace?

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map, arcgis-market-place

I just went to the ArcGIS Marketplace to see if I could buy the latest and greatest Story Map from around the world.  This might be some ripping yarn supported by maps.

When I [searched the ArcGIS Marketplace for 'story map'](https://marketplace.arcgis.com/search.html#t=most_recent&q=%22story%20map%22) the only hit I got was an [Esri Story Maps page](https://marketplace.arcgis.com/listing.html?id=7f803ea8794245e18bf65cd57cca054e) telling me that:

> Creating story maps is included in ArcGIS Online with both ArcGIS
>   Online Public Account and ArcGIS Online Subscription

Using the ArcGIS Marketplace, and only the capabilities included within an ArcGIS Online Subscription (which I have by virtue of my ArcGIS for Desktop maintenance), is it possible to create a Story Map, place a paywall on it, and potentially see revenue trickle in, or what might be a showstopper that would prevent it being that easy?

This is a simplified version of something that I would like to do.  Assume that:

- a Story Map could be authored which is of enough interest to attract an audience who *might* be willing to pay to view it.
- I am an authorized marketplace provider even though that is not currently the case.

This question is about trying to understand how to participate in the ArcGIS Marketplace by using a Story Map which is listed in My Contents of ArcGIS Online as a web map app, as the simplest example of an app that *might* be made available for sale.

Comment: That would probably violate the terms and conditions;  it would certainly violate the spirit of the StoryMap concept.

Comment: @Vince I may not be explaining well - I am trying to understand how someone works within the ArcGIS Marketplace using its design goals to create a revenue stream from apps created using ArcGIS Online. The "paywall" would only be something that I thought may have been part of the Marketplace and a Story Map is just an example of a well understood web map app used to try and clarify how to participate in the Marketplace.

Comment: You may have focused the question to tightly; "StoryMap" and "revenue stream" are a bir discongruent.

Comment: @Vince I thought the Marketplace was about earning revenue in partnership with Esri via  developing and selling ArcGIS Online apps.

Comment: I see apps and data in the FAQ, not maps.

Comment: @Vince I'm away from a browser but in My Content of ArcGIS Online, authored Story Maps are listed as web map apps.  If they are not apps I would be keen to know that with some certainty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To feature your app within the ArcGIS Marketplace, your app will need the end user to login with a Named User.  From its [FAQ](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/marketplace/provider/faq.htm#anchor7):

> All apps in the marketplace must require a named user login.

If you look at the types of apps in the marketplace, they are typically not things like story-maps.  More like native apps, or utility web apps.  With that said, you might still be able to register a story map on ArcGIS Marketplace, as long as it still requires the end-users to login.  Perhaps a free version to entice some users to view it, and a paid version to get to the premium content within the story map.

For your use-purpose, I would recommend having a read of the [ArcGIS Developer Plan terms of use.](https://developers.arcgis.com/terms/)  This is not in relation to ArcGIS Marketplace.

Some relevant excerpts:

> If you want to charge for access to apps you build using ArcGIS Online
>   you have to have a paid subscription.

.

> If you want to generate revenue from your use of ArcGIS Online, you
>   must purchase an ArcGIS Online Standard ELA, Organization or Developer
>   Plan.

.

> The one thing you can never do, though, is sell, share, or sublicense
>   an ArcGIS Online Named User Login Credential to provide access to your
>   subscription. However, you are certainly free to create your own login
>   mechanism that enables your customers to access your applications.

Would recommend getting in touch with Esri if you have a particular use-case in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure that any of the three relevant excerpts apply to me because I have ArcGIS Online for Organizations as part of my ArcGIS for Desktop maintenance, and I am not using a Developer Plan.  Your third paragraph which begins "If you look at the types of apps ..." makes me think you get where I am coming from in trying to understand whether an "atypical" app like a Story Map has a place in the ArcGIS Marketplace.

Comment: I think they do.  You can still login to ArcGIS for Developers with an organisational named user, and get the same benefits as a developer plan.

Comment: OK - I just tried that and registered a test app that I think takes me a step closer to my goal.  I now think that what your answer is saying is that I already have the entitlement to the first two excerpts you quoted, and the third applies to everybody anyway.